# SharePoint 2013 Error: HTTP Error 400.

Tags: error

When I try to edit page (Adding Web Parts) > Save & Close
then I get “HTTP 400 Bad Request” error.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this as I cannot find any reference to it on the google

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the uls log? There should be something in it.

Answer (score 1):

The status code says Bad Request, so the server wouldn't even start processing it. Most likely this is related to bloated or corrupted cookies. Try clearing browser cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the alternate access mapping.

Also use Fiddler (an a browser development tool) to see if certain requests (to Javascript files) are blocked.